# how to create user defined struct for array of different user defined object in golang

Tags: json, go, parsing

I am trying to parse json object in golang.

Below is the json structure :

```
{
    "properties": {
        "alertType": "VM_EICAR",
        "resourceIdentifiers": [{
                "azureResourceId": "/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/vm1",
                "type": "AzureResource"
            },
            {
                "workspaceId": "f419f624-acad-4d89-b86d-f62fa387f019",
                "workspaceSubscriptionId": "20ff7fc3-e762-44dd-bd96-b71116dcdc23",
                "workspaceResourceGroup": "myRg1",
                "agentId": "75724a01-f021-4aa8-9ec2-329792373e6e",
                "type": "LogAnalytics"
            }
        ],

        "vendorName": "Microsoft",
        "status": "New"

    }
}
```

I have below user defined types.

```
type AzureResourceIdentifier struct {
    AzureResourceId                 string                      `json:"azureResourceId"`
    Type                            string                      `json:"type"`           
}
```

```
type LogAnalyticsIdentifier struct{
    AgentId                     string          `json:"agentId"`
    Type                        string          `json:"type"`
    WorkspaceId                 string          `json:"workspaceId"`
    WorkspaceResourceGroup      string          `json:"workspaceResourceGroup"`
    WorkspaceSubscriptionId     string          `json:"workspaceSubscriptionId"`
}
```

I have a top level  user defined type as **properties** as below.
it has resourceIdentifiers as array of two other user defined types(defined above),

- AzureResourceIdentifier
- LogAnalyticsIdentifier

how can I define type of resourceIdentifiers in properties ?

```
type Properties struct{
          alertType               string                        
          resourceIdentifiers               ???                         `
          vendorName                  string                        `
          status              string                           
}
```

Note: I have a existing connector and we are provisioned to input the struct of the parsing json, we cannot override or add any function.

Comment: *"There are some convoluted approach to do it ..."* -- What do you consider a "convoluted approach"? Explain what kind of approaches you are *not* interested in so that people don't waste their time writing up answers that you don't like.

Comment: i understand your point but I am not sure how  downvoting my question will help others to suggest me a solution ?

Comment: I did not downvote so I can't answer that.

Comment: Because the data in the `resourceIdentifiers` array can include both "AzureResourceIdentifier" and "LogAnalyticsIdentifier" I think your best bet would be to create a struct with enough fields for both (say `ResourceIdentifier`) and read into that structure.

Comment: So you mean to say that we cannot create a user defined type for array of different objects ?

sorry, i have simplified the fields for easy to understand.

Comment: @Monu with your edits you made the example quite useless. The json in the original question at least had some info about the types of the properties, now the json is meaningless. With data like that, the only thing you can do is use `[]interface{}` or `[]map[string]interface{}` for the properties field. Also note that unexported fields will *not* get unmarshaled no matter what. You need exported fields. And even if this is just an "example" that does not mean that it acceptable to provide completely useless and misleading code.

Comment: i have put it back again.
I am sorry , I am new to go.
@HectorCorrea suggested me to create a single structure to have all fields in same struct, I am not sure how can we do that that will parse the json ?
Could you please suggest me?

Comment: Consider this approach @Monu: https://go.dev/play/p/D8ZpJm4Sq9Z

Comment: thank you for the suggestion.
I should have mentioned it before that I have a connector and we are provisioned to input the struct of the parsing json, we cannot override or add any function. 
Thats why I thought if there is any way i could define the type ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of options here.

1. `[]map[string]interface{}`

Using a map will allow any JSON object in the array to be parsed, but burdens you with having to safely extract information after the fact.

2. `[]interface{}`

Each is going to be a map under the hood, unless non-JSON object elements can also be in the JSON array. No reason to use it over `map[string]interface{}` in your case.

3. A slice of a new struct type which covers all possible fields: `[]ResourceIdentifier`

```golang
type ResourceIdentifier struct {
    AzureResourceId             string `json:"azureResourceId"`
    AgentId                     string `json:"agentId"`
    WorkspaceId                 string `json:"workspaceId"`
    WorkspaceResourceGroup      string `json:"workspaceResourceGroup"`
    WorkspaceSubscriptionId     string `json:"workspaceSubscriptionId"`
    
    Type                        string `json:"type"`
}
```

This is probably the laziest solution. It allows you to get where you want to quickly, at the cost of wasting some memory and creating a non self-explanatory data design which might cause confusion if later trying to serialize with it again.

4. A new struct type + custom unmarshalling implementation.

```golang
type ResourceIdentifiers struct {
    AzureResourceIdentifiers []AzureResourceIdentifier
    LogAnalyticsIdentifiers []LogAnalyticsIdentifier
}
```

Implement `json.Unmarshaler` to decide which type of struct to construct and in which slice to put it.

Comment: thanks , slice seems to be most innocuous approach.  we cannot change json format as its coming for microsoft security cloud api .